# Mocking/skipping sleep calls in unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

What is the general approach in unit tests for methods that involve a sleep() call?

Lets say I have the class:

```
class Foo {
    public bool someMethodWithSleep() {
        bool failed = false;

        for (int i = 0 : 5) {
            failed = trySomething(); // mocked to return false
            if (failed) {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            } else { return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In test cases for failures that call this function (directly or nested), I dont want it to sleep for 25+ seconds and slowing every test file that calls it. What's the best approach to skip the sleep calls in unit tests?

Comment: My thoughts are to extract business/functional logic in to methods where possible and wrap them with sleep calls; testing only the extracted logic. Meaning here i will not write tests for someMethodWithSleep, only for trySomething.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it with a dependency.

```
class Foo {
    private final Sleeper sleeper;
    public Foo(final Sleeper sleeper) {
        this.sleeper = sleeper;
    }
    public Foo() {
        this(SecondsSleeper.INSTANCE);
    }

    public bool someMethodWithSleep() {
        bool failed = false;

        for (int i = 0 : 5) {
            failed = trySomething(); // mocked to return false
            if (failed) {
                sleeper.sleep(5);
            } else { return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
interface Sleeper {
  void sleep(int duration);
}
enum SecondsSleeper implements Sleeper {
  INSTANCE;
  void sleep(final int seconds) {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(seconds);
  }
}
enum TestSleeper implements Sleeper {
  INSTANCE;
  void sleepSeconds(final int duration) {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

Then in your real application, create Foo as `new Foo()` and in your test as `new Foo(TestSleeper.INSTANCE)`

Comment: Thanks! Im also wondering if there is some catch all code so that all `sleep()` calls in test files will be skipped or timed 0 to avoid refractoring code and cases where the coder isnt aware sleep() is nested when writing tests?

Comment: @Jacob You could introduce a Singleton which needs to be used by all methods. This singleton then has an `internalSleeper` field which can be changed globally between `SecondsSleeper` and `TestSleeper` (or a simple boolean flag which will be checked in the sleep method). Of course: all using classes must use the new singleton and disabling the sleep in the test will affect _all_ classes.